# how to display images of different sizes in a fixed size area in template wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I can't make the images automatically adapt to the size of the area.
What I want to do: For example, if an image has dimensions 500 x 500, display 750 x 450. If an image is 1024x512, display 750x450.

Already try using add_image_size, but the images do not display the same size.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property in CSS on the images you want to fill the area.
This creates a `background-size: cover` effect on the images and stretches them.

```
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```